# Disk is full even though it is not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

df-h gets me

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

 udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev

 tmpfs           785M  9,7M  775M   2% /run

 /dev/sdb5        15G   14G     0 100% /

 tmpfs           3,9G  1,3M  3,9G   1% /dev/shm

 tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock

 tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

 tmpfs           785M   32K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
```

After that i tried deleting some files which were about 100MB went into vim wrote a single line and save failed. Sudo apt-get autoclean doesn't do anything at all sudo apt-get -f autoremove gets me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc++1 libjpeg62
Suggested packages:
  clang
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64 linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
  linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic snap-confine thermald
  ubuntu-core-launcher
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc++1 libjpeg62
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 21 to remove and 475 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 304 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1265 MB disk space will be freed.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

which gets me nowhere since i cant install a single bit.

Looked for some other solutions like one that said i should run

```
# tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sdb5
```

but nothing changed and then i restarted my pc in case of deleted files that are still open and as such don't release memory and `lsof|grep delete` didnt give anything.

Comment: sudo apt-get clean doesn't do anything. Deleted the cache as you instructed, still nothing.

Comment: Waht says `df -i`? You could have exhausted all your inodes.

Comment: yeah forgot to write about it. Everything but /dev/sdb5, is in 1% iuse and /dev/sdb5is at 48%

Comment: and `fsck` says the disk is clean?

Comment: `fsck from util-linux 2.27.1

e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)

/dev/sdb5 is mounted.

e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`